# Add Line Breaks to ADF Text File Output (Can this be done with Logic Apps or Mapping Data Flows)?

Tags: azure-data-factory

My ADF pipeline created a very long text fixed field file where the following is just a few of the first several characters.

10E20131216330785887BMECOL 00 Stephen Hughes M 19780319 12 20210711330785887BMECOL

We have to put a line break before the 12 shown in bold above so it will appear on the next line. Does anyone have any ideas how this can be done? We have to meet the specifications of a vendor is why this text file has to be produced in this manner.

Thanks!
Mike Kiser

Comment: can you provide more information on how you are getting the files and constructing this text, is this a text file output from a copy activity?

Comment: Yes, this is a text file as the output Sink of a Copy Activity. The text file looks perfect all but the line breaks at specific points in the text.  Thanks

Comment: Is the data after the newline are meant to be new row in the dataset? Maybe you could provide an example of source data and transformation needed to get the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it in ADF using Data Flow but could not achieve as there are no direct ways to do this in ADF- Azure Functions , Azure Batch services using Shell Scripts where you have to write own script to new line.